# How can I make a two column table?

Tags: tables

I want to make a two column table whose column titles are Hyperparameter and Optimal Value.

I wrote this code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{More columns.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \textbf{Hyperparameter} & \textbf{Optimal Value}\\
      \hline
      base_estimator__C & 1.0 \\ 
      base_estimator__decision_function_shape & ovo\\ 
      base_estimator__kernel & Linear\\ 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

It doesn't work, giving multiple errors.

Comment: add a `backslash \` before the `underscore` and add package `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
-- also suggest use `booktabs` package and use `toprule, midrule, bottomrule` for better spacing as in the answer below -- also suggest remove vertical lines

Comment: I removed the `tabularx` tag since you don't use this package in your code. Ragarding the error messags you should get upon trying to compile your code, you might want to take a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554241/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \caption{More columns.}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \textbf{Hyperparameter} & \textbf{Optimal Value}\\
                \hline
                base\_estimator\_C & 1.0 \\ 
                base\_estimator\_decision\_function\_shape & ovo\\ 
                base\_estimator\_kernel & Linear\\ 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

edit

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \caption{More columns.}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular}{cc}\toprule
                \textbf{Hyperparameter} & \textbf{Optimal Value}\\
                \midrule
                base\_estimator\_C & 1.0 \\ 
                base\_estimator\_decision\_function\_shape & ovo\\ 
                base\_estimator\_kernel & Linear\\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternative examples:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcommand{\myverbatim}[1]{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
            \caption{More columns.}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular}{>{\collectcell\myverbatim}l<{\endcollectcell}c}\toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Hyperparameter}} & \textbf{Optimal Value}\\
                \midrule
                base_estimator_C & 1.0 \\ 
                base_estimator_decision_function_shape & ovo\\ 
                base_estimator_kernel & Linear\\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
            \caption{More columns.}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular}{lc}\toprule
                \textbf{Hyperparameter} & \textbf{Optimal Value}\\
                \midrule
                base_estimator_C & 1.0 \\ 
                base_estimator_decision_function_shape & ovo\\ 
                base_estimator_kernel & Linear\\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]