# Latex ``helpfully" inserts missing $ for math mode, when I don't want math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm trying to compile a document in overleaf where I need to quote a reviewer comment.
The comment has underscores in a word i.e. Number_of_Nodes.

For some reason I think the compiler sees the underscores and tries to be helpful by adding $ to enter inline math mode. Firstly, I don't want math mode, and secondly this conflicts with the quote environment.

How can I stop this "helpful" behaviour?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\itshape 
(Number_of_Nodes_at_step(n)).
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you want `(Number\textunderscore of\textunderscore Nodes\textunderscore at\textunderscore step(n)).`. `_` has a special meaning: it creates subscripts in math mode, which is why TeX switches to math mode.

Comment: `(Number\_of\_Nodes\_at\_step(n))`?

Comment: See also: [Prevent LaTeX from thinking I'm writing an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554241/134144)

Comment: If you are using OpTeX instead LaTeX, then you can write `{\it (Number_of_Nodes_at_step(n))}` without problems. :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\textunderscore` instead, `_` switches to math mode

Edit:

You could also escape `_` character with `\_`

Like this `(Number\_of\_Nodes\_at\_step(n))`

Thanks Don Hosek and Zarko!

Comment: `\_` is the usual command or printing an underscore.

Comment: See my comment below question ...